# Não consigo resolver esse erro no Python, sou iniciante

Tags: python

Bom eu preciso fazer essa multiplicação mas da o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Guilherme\Desktop\dasdsa.py", line 17, in <module>
    conta = (trans1) * trans2
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'tuple'
```

O que eu faço? Eu preciso de um tipo de variavel que faça a multiplicação com virgula? porque tentei colocar em float mas mesmo assim não funcionou, eu nao conseguia converter o trans1 para float, quais minhas opções?

MEU CODIGO:

```
import urllib.request

page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://dolarhoje.com/")
text = page.read().decode("utf8")

price = text[9938:9942]

trans1 = (price)
tuple(price)

usertap = input("Coloque o real aqui:")
trans2 = tuple(usertap)
conta = (trans1) * trans2

print(conta)
```

Comment: BTW, tem uma linha com um `tuple(price)` sozinho que não faz nada. O título da sua pergunta também podia ser mais específico.

Answer (score 1):

Se o erro é em função da vírgulça no lugar do ponto, é só substituí-lo. Pelo código que você mostra, não há necessidade de usar tuplas, podendo ficar assim:

```
import urllib.request

page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://dolarhoje.com/")
text = page.read().decode("utf8")

raw_price = text[9938:9942]
# substitui a pontuação e converte para float
price = float(raw_price.replace(',', '.'))

raw_usertap = input("Coloque o real aqui: ")
# o mesmo procedimento feito anteriormente só que com a entrada do usuário
usertap = float(raw_usertap.replace(',', '.'))

conta = price * usertap

print(conta)
```

Answer (score 0):

No seu programa, `trans1` e `trans2` são do tipo tupla (aparentemente, tuplas de caracteres). Para fazer a contra você precisa que sejam números

```
trans1 = float(price)
trans2 = float(usertap)
```

Comment: Então, eu já tentei deixar em float mas da o seguinte erro:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Guilherme\Desktop\dasdsa.py", line 11, in <module>
    float(price)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '3,88'

Comment: O problema é que ele não consegue converter a vírgula. Se fosse um ponto funcionava.

Comment: Então o único jeito seria, eu mudar o que esta dentro de price? No caso esta 3,87. Eu teria que mudar isso? Só assim funcionaria?

Comment: Isso é uma maneira de resolver o problema.

Answer (score 0):

O correto seria transformar ambas as variáveis para um mesmo tipo (No caso, ou um número inteiro ou ponto flutuante). Algo assim:

```
trans1 = Float(price)
trans2 = Float(usertap)
```

No entanto, o trecho da página que você escolheu (Armazenando em price) está resultando em letras, não números. Provavelmente devido alterações no site ou algo assim... Eu recomendaria o uso do BeautifulSoup na hora da manipulação do arquivo HTML para evitar esse tipo de erro.